# How to partition a hard drive but not delete it's content?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I want to install Xubuntu on my friend's computer. There is one hard drive but multiple partitions. She doesn't want to delete Windows 10, but she wants to devote a large part of her hard drive to Linux, and a little part to Windows.

So this is what we think we should do : keep the partition with Windows installed, give it some place on the hard drive (~50GB), and dedicate the rest to Xubuntu.

If I remember right, there is a main partition with about 900GB and 3 or 4 others with a few GB each. Is it possible to split this partition into 2 partitions but not delete what's on it ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility in Windows called Disk Management("create and format hard disk partitions" in the control panel). Open that, right-click your Windows data partition, and click 'shrink volume'. This will automatically shrink both the partition and the NTFS filesystem. Note  that you can only shrink until you reach an immovable file- but these are usually all at the start of the partition, so I'd expect that you would be able to shrink it down a fair amount.

When you're done, just boot the Xubuntu installer. If I remember correctly, this should be the same as the regular one- it should, in theory, offer an option to use the free space on your hard drive to install the OS. If not, choose "something else" in the menu where it asks where you want to install the OS, and then create a new partition in Gparted.

Lastly- if there are any problems with the Xubuntu installer, I recommend installing a regular Ubuntu image and running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
```

to convert to Xubuntu(the so-called 'flavors' are really the same exact operating system with different DEs pre-installed)

Comment: +1 for the answer which does not need third party software.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this software for years: [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/download/epmf-download.html)

1. Install the software
2. Run The Application.
3. Choose C: Drive
4. Resize Partition
5. After you resized the partition, you will have `*` unallocated
   space. Next you will choose the `*` unallocated space and "Convert
   to Logical".

[Step by step execution HERE](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Dual-boot-Linux-and-Windows-on-a-PC-with-W/?ALLSTEPS)

**Preferred:**

However, I do recomment using an old laptop that nobody wants and format the HDD and install a nice clean version of Ubuntu; Although I prefer Centos.

**Another Alternative**: **WUBI**, a version of Linux on top of Windows.

- No partition necessary. Installs/Uninstalls like any Windows App.
- Direct [DOWNLOAD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wubi/files/latest/download) from SourceForge.net or the site bookmark
  [HERE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wubi/)
- CNET has a link also [DOWNLOAD](http://download.cnet.com/Wubi/3001-2094_4-10701841.html?hasJs=n&hlndr=1) or visit [HERE](http://download.cnet.com/Wubi/3000-2094_4-10701841.html)
- Or you can just search for WUBI and install it from a link of your choice.
- Sources and Wubi info links (thanks @ngng): [wubi-info](https://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info) and [Github-releases-Wubi](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases)

**Additionally...**

- [BootUS](http://www.boot-us.com/download.htm) a Boot Manager Software for MBR
- [Craig Chamberlin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4-eNXAxGU8&list=PLdihP57p-PDhyQBZQ6cBd2eIaobZyT-9A), I learned my first Dual Boot right here. He talks about good ways to dual boot for success and setting up a shared drive while you are setting up partitions. Good idea!

Comment: Xubuntu is just Ubuntu with Xfce as default DE. It's not some special "version of Ubuntu that runs on top of your windows". You may or may not be referring to Wubi, which has been discontinued, though.

Comment: @TomYan Oh yeah. You are correct. I forgot the name Wubi, yes. Really discontinued? It's still available in places. Maybe the site is down, but it's still out there. It was good way to get a taste of Linux when I first started using Linux for college; the Uni I attended were Linux crazy. I did try Wubi, then I did a dual boot, then I dedicated a laptop to an OS, Centos flavour. Thanks for the info.

Comment: IMHO currently, Wubi is only an option if you use a [community supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases). see also [Wubi info at askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info)

Comment: @ngng Good info on Wubi. ngng links a site on Github why Wubi was no longer supported due to new OS and why it's now maintained by the "Community";  As is most Linux Open Source.